# Filter rows based on two fields, where one of them contains a selection criterion

Tags: postgresql

Given the following table

```
group | weight | category_id | category_name_plus
    1       10           100   Ab
    1       20           101   Bcd
    1       30           100   Efghij
    2       10           101   Bcd
    2       20           101   Cdef
    2       30           100   Defgh
    2       40           100   Ab
    3       10           102   Fghijkl
    3       20           101   Ab
```

The "weight" is unique for each group and is also an indicator for the order of records inside the group.

What I want is to retrieve one record per group filtered by category_id, but only the record having the highest "weight" inside its "group".

Example for filtering by category_id = 100:

```
group | weight | category_id | category_name_plus
    1       30           100   Efghij
    2       40           100   Ab
```

Example for filtering by category_id = 101:

```
group | weight | category_id | category_name_plus
    1       20           101   Bcd
    2       20           101   Cdef
    3       20           101   Ab
```

**How can I select just these rows?**

I tried fiddling with `UNIQUE`, `MAX(category_id)` etc. but I'm still unable to get the correct results. The main problem for me is to get the `category_name_plus` value here.

I am working with PostgreSQL 9.4(beta 3), because I also need various other niceties like `"WITH ORDINALITY"` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `rank` [window function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html) should do the trick:

```sql
SELECT "group", weight, category_id, category_name_plus
FROM   (SELECT "group", weight, category_id, category_name_plus,
               RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY "group" 
                            ORDER BY weight DESC) AS rk
        FROM   my_table) t
WHERE  rk = 1 AND category_id = 101
```

Note:
"group" is a reserved word in SQL, so it has to be surrounded by quotes in order to be used as a column name. It would probably be better, though, to replace it with a non-reserved word, such as "group_id".

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (category_id) *
from your_table
order by category_id, weight desc
```